# Preserve order when converting a delimited string to a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to preserve the record order, which is provided as comma delimited string. The 5<sup>th</sup> item in by delimited string is a null. I need the 5<sup>th</sup> row to be null as well.

```
 with test as 
(select 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,,MNO' str from dual  
  )  
  select rownum, regexp_substr (str, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) split  
    from test  
 connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace (str, '[^,]+' ))  + 1
```

The current result I'm getting puts this in the 6<sup>th</sup> position:

```
1   ABC
2   DEF
3   GHI
4   JKL
5   MNO
6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order **is** preserved by your expression, but your regular expression doesn't match nulls correctly, so the 5th item disappears. The 6th row is a `NULL` because there are no more match after the 5th match.

You could do this instead:

```
SQL> with test as
  2  (select 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,,MNO' str from dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT rownum,
  5         rtrim(regexp_substr(str || ',', '[^,]*,', 1, rownum), ',') split
  6    FROM test
  7  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(str, '[^,]+')) + 1;

    ROWNUM SPLIT
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
         1 ABC
         2 DEF
         3 GHI
         4 JKL
         5 
         6 MNO

6 rows selected
```

Or this:

```
SQL> with test as
  2  (select 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,,MNO' str from dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT rownum,
  5         regexp_substr(str, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, rownum, 'i', 1) split
  6    FROM test
  7  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(str, '[^,]+')) + 1;

    ROWNUM SPLIT
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 ABC
         2 DEF
         3 GHI
         4 JKL
         5 
         6 MNO

6 rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks @Vincent, that works. Also I have one more question, can have the delimiter of my choice, I would like to put this code into a proc and pass the delimiter as parameter. Is there a possibility in above method?

Comment: Of course, pass the delimiter as argument and replace every instance of `,` by the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
SELECT
      STR,
      REPLACE ( SUBSTR ( STR,
                     CASE LEVEL
                         WHEN 1
                         THEN
                             0
                         ELSE
                             INSTR ( STR,
                                    '~',
                                    1,
                                    LEVEL
                                    - 1 )
                     END
                     + 1,
                     1 ),
              '~' )
FROM
      (SELECT 'A~~C~~E' AS STR FROM DUAL)
CONNECT BY
      LEVEL <= LENGTH ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( STR,
                                  '[^~]+' ) )
             + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works..

```
SELECT
      ROWNUM,
      CAST ( REGEXP_SUBSTR ( STR,
                        '(.*?)(,|$)',
                        1,
                        LEVEL,
                        NULL,
                        1 ) AS CHAR ( 12 ) )
          OUTPUT
FROM
      (SELECT 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,,MNO' AS STR FROM DUAL)
CONNECT BY
      LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT ( STR,
                         ',' )
             + 1;
```

Comment: Why would you cast the result to a `CHAR`?